# ActiveMQ Artemis metrics in Kibana Elastic?

Tags: java, kibana, activemq-artemis

Based on [the ActiveMQ Artemis documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/metrics.html) is it possible to have metrics displayed in Kibana with the help of [this plugin](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/tree/main/implementations/micrometer-registry-elastic)?

I am not able to use it, and I did not find any example of how to do that.

Did anyone experience this situation?

Answer (score 0):

There's multiple layers here.

First, the ActiveMQ Artemis documentation you cited details a plugin interface for *the broker* itself. This is provided because Micrometer supports [**a lot** of different registries](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/tree/main/implementations) and the broker cannot support them all. Therefore this plugin interface is provided so users can implement their own plugins to support whatever Micrometer registry they want.

Second, the Micrometer link you provided is for a Micrometer registry implementation. This is what you'd use in your `ActiveMQMetricsPlugin` implementation in order to display metrics in Kibana.

The ActiveMQ Artemis documentation you linked basically says the same thing:

> Important runtime metrics have been instrumented via the Micrometer API, and all a user needs to do is implement `org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.metrics.ActiveMQMetricsPlugin` in order to instantiate and configure a `io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry` implementation. Relevant implementations of MeterRegistry are available from the [Micrometer code-base](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/tree/master/implementations).